# RxJS - use operator on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I get some data from an API and want to fetch it using rxjs's .pipe. What I want to do is to apply an filter if some variable is true. 
 Here's my working Code: (The UserService returns the API response)

**TS**

```js
this.filteredOptions =  this.userService
  .getUserSuggestions(this.displayName, 30)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.filter(option => option.eMail != null)),
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
```

Want I want now is to only apply the filter if some variable I set above is true. I tried some stuff with iif() but on my current understanding iif() can't be used to apply different operators.

Greetings!

**Solved!**

```js
map(response => this.someVariable ? response : response.filter(option => option.eMail != null)),
```

Use the variable within the map operator. Thanks @Flix

Comment: You can just add the variable condition in the map, like this: `map(response => someVariable ? response.filter(option => option.eMail != null) : response)`

Comment: Solved! I tried this before but placed the variable within the filter operator... Thank!

Comment: @KastenBrot Please accept the right answer instead of editing your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: There only was a comment before, is there a way to accept an comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the variable condition in the map, like this:

```
this.filteredOptions =  this.userService
  .getUserSuggestions(this.displayName, 30)
  .pipe(
    map(response => someVariable ? response.filter(option => option.eMail != null) : response),
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use the `filter` Operator:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter.

`.pipe(filter(conditionFn))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` as below:

```
this.filteredOptions =  this.userService
  .getUserSuggestions(this.displayName, 30)
  .pipe(
    filter(response => response.filter(option => option.eMail != null)),
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
```